# Is it possible to create a Shopify App with Python?

Tags: python, web-applications, shopify

I got a question about app development for Shopify and hope someone can shed some light on the process. Background: I am studying Web Design & Development and at the moment, i am researching topics for my major project. I got limited experience with setting up a Shopify Shop and making minor changes to the front-end and javascript, but nothing too deep. One of the ideas i have as a major project is creating an application for Shopify.

Now the question how does creating a shopify app work? Can i just create an application with Python and implement it into Shopify?

If anyone could give any insights or experiences with this topic, i would really appreciate it.

Greetings,

Sven

Comment: You can definitely use the Shopify API to manipulate your Shopify project. There already exists a [python api wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/ShopifyAPI/) for Shopify

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Django / Flask web framework to create a Shopify app. However, Shopify app development is opinionated towards Node, Rails and React. It will have a steeper learning curve than other languages.

You can refer to this official repo to create a sample Shopify Django App: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_django_app